# how to clear varnish cache for node queues?

Tags: caching, action, rules, varnish, pressflow

We installed node queue module on pressflow 6 + varnish. For clearing the varnish cache for node queues, we developed  rules using rules,cache action modules. But the issue comes, whenever we update the content,it is reflecting for logged in users, but it is not reflecting for anonymous users.Could you please suggest us for how to clear varnish cache with rules or any custom code?

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

in the CLI:

ban.url .

This will clear the cache.